# Why isn't 0-padding allowed in Python?

Tags: python

I've just noticed 0-padding is not allowed in Python and I was wondering why this choice was made?

For example:

```
a = 09
```

doesn't work while

```
a = 9
```

does

How's that?!

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Invalid Token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336181/python-invalid-token)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python, as many other languages, treat numbers starting with 0 as being in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation. 09 is not valid as octal

See [chapter 2.4.4](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals) in the python language reference.

Comment: That said, in Python 3, octal nubers are preceded with 0o instead of a mere 0.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that while chatting with colleagues and completely forgot to check before asking that question :/

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what @nos said:

```
>>> a = 01
>>> a
1
>>> a = 07
>>> a
7
>>> a = 010
>>> a
8
>>> a = 08
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 08
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

So, `a = 010` is octal `10`, which is decimal 8. Octal only knows digits 0 through 7. So that is why this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's because numbers starting with 0 are octal numbers, and octal figures go from 0 to 7!

Doing `a = 07` is perfectly accepted, as an octal; so `a = 061` will lead `a` to contain 49.