# Invalid token error while making dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Hi I have two set of columns in the text file column 1 is yyyy-mm-dd and column2 is precipitation. I want to extract the precipitation value only for April through August. In order to get that, I split the line and extract only month from column 1. Then try to make dictionary for month and precipitation and use a if statement to match the months and append the corresponding precipitation value in an empty array.

While doing that, I am getting an "invalid token" error in my if statement for month==08 in the code below:

Code:

```
file1 = open("test.txt","r")

Growing-period=[]
Intermediate-period=[]
Dormant-period=[]
for line in file1:
  line2 = line.split()
  WQ = line2[1]
  month = line2[0].split("-")[1]
  dct1={month:WQ}
  for k,v in dct1.item():
     if (month==04 or month==05 or month==06 or month==07 or month==08):
        Growing-period.append(dct[v])
     print Growing-period
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated! Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the zeros to the left to compare numbers.

You can replace your

```
if (month==04 or month==05 or month==06 or month==07 or month==08):
```

with

```
if month in (4,5,6,7,8):
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336181/python-invalid-token/336189#336189) answer, the preceeding zero turns your number into an octal and consequently causes the syntax error because `08` is not a valid octal representation.