# How to generate unique random numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, random, unique

I know that I should write a code to random numbers like the code below, but I don't know how to generate unique numbers, for example I want to generate 3 unique phone numbers from a list at once, how can I do it?

```
import random  

# last numbers of the phone numbers are in order, 1,2,3,4,5,6
myList = [60165651, 60175652, 60156523, 60135354, 60159535, 60192326]  

for x in range(5): 
    print(random.choice(myList))
```

### -----------------------------------------------------

another problem is that if I put zero at the beginning of numbers I get an error: Token invalid!

e.g:

```
myPhoneList = [060165651, 60175652, 60156523, 60135354, 60159535, 60192326]
```

Comment: You're trying to ***sample*** the input list of numbers, not ***generate*** it (as an output).

Comment: And sampling N unique items is called ***sampling without replacement***. See the doc for [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random.sample#random.sample)

Comment: 2nd issue: Putting zero at the beginning of a number tells Python it's octal (base-8), but then your number can't contain the digits 8,9, that's why it throws an error. Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778699/python-syntaxerror-invalid-token-on-numbers-starting-with-0-zeroes). So if you really want to have a decimal phone number with leading zero, use a list of strings, not integers.

Comment: There is a special module `faker` to generate a fake data. You can use it to get fake numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

```
from random import sample

myList = [60165651, 60175652, 60156523, 60135354, 60159535, 60192326]  
print(sample(myList, 3))
# [60192326, 60165651, 60175652]
```